# How would you hide the overflow of X but avoid Y from becoming scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned image that I want to overlap the section below, but I want to hide the overflow on the x Axis to stop it from making the window too wide. Using `overflow-x: hidden;` fixes my issue, but the image then becomes scrollable rather than overlapping the section below as intended. Looking through MDN and W3, I understand that you cannot have x = hidden and y = visible simulatenously.

The simplest solution seems to be that I go into photoshop and cut the image as necessary, set `left/right: 0` to stick to the side and leave it at that, but I want to have the image full sized just in case I want to reposition the image for mobile and would prefer to avoid using 2 images and classes that toggle with media queries if possible.

Are there other solutions to this issue?

Comment: I think it should be as simple as `img {max-width: 100%}`

Comment: @Morpheus - I want it to overflow on the x axis, but I don't want that overflow to be visible. I've already tried this before, with no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you create an example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem in that case?

Comment: [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) (perhaps together with [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)) might do the trick

Comment: Have you tried using `clip-path` (with `clip` for backwards compatibility)?